# Improve list parsing command

Tags: token-lists

> **This question led to part of a new package:**
>   [`menukeys`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/menukeys)

I build a command to iterate over a list with changable seperators and it works like expected but I wonder if there is a faster or more elegant way to do it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\def\tw@first@element#1{\fbox{\strut#1 (first)}}
\def\tw@middle@element#1{\fbox{\strut#1 (mid)}}
\def\tw@last@element#1{\fbox{\strut#1 (last)}}
\def\tw@single@element#1{\fbox{\strut#1 (single)}}

\def\tw@seperator{\fbox{\strut sep}}
\def\tw@precode{\fbox{\strut pre}}
\def\tw@postcode{\fbox{\strut post}}

\newcounter{tw@list@i}
\newcounter{tw@list@last}

\def\tw@input@seperator{,}

\DeclareListParser{\tw@do@menu}{,}
\DeclareListParser{\tw@do@list@count}{,}

\NewDocumentCommand{\setmenuseperator}{v}{%
   \let\tw@do@menu\relax%
   \let\tw@do@list@count\relax%
   \DeclareListParser{\tw@do@menu}{#1}%
   \DeclareListParser{\tw@do@list@count}{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\menu}[1]{%
   \setcounter{tw@list@i}{1}%
   \setcounter{tw@list@last}{0}%
   \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\stepcounter{tw@list@last}}%
   \tw@do@list@count{#1}%
   \tw@precode%
   \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
      \ifnumequal{1}{\value{tw@list@last}}{%
         \tw@single@element{##1}%
      }{%
         \ifnumequal{1}{\value{tw@list@i}}{%
            \tw@first@element{##1}%
         }{%
            \ifnumequal{\value{tw@list@i}}{\value{tw@list@last}}{%
               \tw@seperator\tw@last@element{##1}%
            }{%
               \tw@seperator\tw@middle@element{##1}%
            }%
         }%
      }%
      \stepcounter{tw@list@i}%
   }%
   \tw@do@menu{#1}%
   \tw@postcode%
}

\makeatother

\setlength{\parskip}{1cm}
\begin{document}
\menu{1,2,3,4}

\menu{Single Element}

\menu{A,B,C,D,E}

\setmenuseperator{/}
\menu{C:/Nutzer und Einstellungen/Desktop/Test}

% doesn’t work yet
%\setmenuseperator{\}
%\menu{C:\Nutzer und Einstellungen\Desktop\Test} 
\end{document}
```

The requirements for the `\menu` command are the following

- Special treatment for single item lists
- Treat first and last list item other than the mid ones
- Insert a separator only between the elements
- add some code before and after the list

### Extra

As you can imagine such commands should be used to format paths automatically, so it would be great if a `\` could be recognized as list separator.

Comment: +1 for taking the effort to turn this into a -- well-documented -- package. Good work!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *catoptions* package has exactly the type of list processor you need. Call `\menu` using the syntax

```
\menu[<list separator>]{<list>}
```

The `<list separator>` can be anything you like, but if it is  backslash (ie, `\`), then specify it (`<list separator>`) as either `bslash` or `backslash`. See examples below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{catoptions}[2011/12/17]

% One command (\tobiprint) replaces 7 commands by Tobi:
\robust@def*\tobiprint#1#2{\fbox{\strut#2\ifblankTF{#1}{}{~(#1)}}}

% We want to test if the <list separator> is 'bslash' or 'backslash'. For the
% test to be valid, we have to separate 'bslash' and 'backslash'. We ordinarily
% would have used comma (,) to do the splitting, but comma is also an admissible
% value for <list separator>. In fact, any character is a valid value for 
% <list separator>. Therefore, the splitter has to be a character that the user
% is unlikely to submit as the <list separator>. One such character is character
% number 1 (^^A). Hence the comma in the definition of \testlistsep is actually
% character ^^A.
% Secondly, <list separator> may have been specified by the user with spurious 
% leading and trailing spaces. Users do this to prettify their code. That is the 
% reason for calling \cpttrimspaces in \testlistsep.
\begingroup
\lccode`\,=1
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \robust@def*\testlistsep#1{%
    \xifinsetTF{,\cpttrimspaces{#1},}{,bslash,backslash,directory,location,}%
  }%
}
\newcommand\menu[2][,]{%
  \tobiprint{}{pre}%
  % \indrisloop accepts any user-specified operator. Let us call yours \tobido:
  \def\tobido##1{%
    \iflastindris
      \ifnum\indrisnr=\@ne
        \tobiprint{single}{##1}%
      \else
        \tobiprint{}{sep}\tobiprint{last}{##1}%
      \fi
    \else
      \ifnum\indrisnr=\@ne
        \tobiprint{first}{##1}%
      \else
        \tobiprint{}{sep}\tobiprint{middle}{##1}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
  \testlistsep{#1}{%
    \edef\alist{\detokenize{#2}}\edef\@tempa{\@backslashchar}%
  }{%
    \edef\alist{\unexpanded{#2}}\edef\@tempa{\detokenize{#1}}%
  }%
  \cptexpanded{\indrisloop*[\@tempa]}\alist\tobido
  \tobiprint{}{post}%
}
\cptrobustify\menu
\edef\cpt@parserlist{\cpt@parserlist\@backslashchar}
\makeatother
% Tests:
\begin{document}
\parindent-40pt
\menu{1,2,3,4}
\par\medskip
\menu{Single Element}
\par\medskip
\menu{A,B,C,D,E}
\par\medskip
\menu[/]{C:/Nutzer und Einstellungen/Desktop/Test}
\par\medskip
\menu[bslash]{C:\Nutzer und Einstellungen\Desktop\Test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Looks very nice and I prefer the 2e solution against @egregs L3 one since I can’T read it. Could you please explain your code a little more detailed (especially the lines 5–9)?

Comment: @Tobi: I have added explanatory notes as requested.

Comment: Why is it faster?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Please I don't understand your question, if it was meant for me.

Comment: Thank you. But what does the `\begin`-/`\endgroup` construct do; I wonder wh it works since they are unbalanced with the braces. And why are you using `\lowercase`?

Comment: @AhmedMusa Please forget my question. I thought the original poster was asking for a more elegant and faster method, but Tobi asked for a more elegant or faster method.

Comment: I removed `\detokenize` form the definition of `\@tempa` and it seems to work. Could this cause any problems?

Comment: Is it ok with you if I include this code in a package? You’ll be mentioned in the manual and source certainly.

Comment: I didn't expect `\menu[bslash]{C:\Nutzer und Einstellungen\Desktop\Test}` to work without `\detokenize{#1}`. Don't trust it to always work. For example, `\Nutzer` may be flagged by TeX as an undefined control sequence in some situations. Without detokenizing, a verbatim or `\scantokens` trickery will be needed. Your question on `\lowercase` will take you into, eg, the TeXBook. You can include the code anywhere you like.

Comment: Hello. Can maybe someone explain the code: 
`% One command (\tobiprint) replaces 7 commands by Tobi:
\robust@def*\tobiprint#1#2{\fbox{\strut#2\ifblankTF{#1}{}{~(#1)}}}`  What is it for and how does it work?

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_tobi_menu_seq
\tl_new:N \l_tobi_sep_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_tobi_sep_tl { , } % default
\tl_const:Nx \c_tobi_backslash_tl { \cs_to_str:N \\ }

\NewDocumentCommand{\setmenuseparator}{ m }
  {
   \tl_set:Nn \l_tobi_sep_tl { #1 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\menu}{ s m }
  {
   \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {
     \group_begin:
     \tl_set_eq:NN \l_tobi_sep_tl \c_tobi_backslash_tl
     \tl_set_rescan:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl {\char_set_catcode_other:N \\ } { #2 }
     \exp_args:NV \tobi_menu_process:n \l_tmpa_tl
     \group_end:
    }
    {
     \tobi_menu_process:n { #2 }
    }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_menu_process:n #1

   \exp_args:NNV \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tobi_menu_seq \l_tobi_sep_tl { #1 }
   \tobi_premenu:
   \prg_case_int:nnn { \seq_length:N \l_tobi_menu_seq }
     {
      { 0 } { EMPTY }
      { 1 } { \tobi_singlemenu:n { \seq_map_function:NN \l_tobi_menu_seq \use:n } }
     }
     {
      \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tobi_menu_seq \l_tmpa_tl
      \seq_pop_right:NN \l_tobi_menu_seq \l_tmpb_tl
      \tobi_firstmenu:n { \l_tmpa_tl}
      \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tobi_menu_seq { \tobi_midmenu:n { ##1 } }
      \tobi_lastmenu:n { \l_tmpb_tl }
     }
   \tobi_postmenu:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_premenu: { \fbox{\strut pre} }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_postmenu: { \fbox{\strut post} }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_firstmenu:n #1 { \fbox{\strut #1~(first)} }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_midmenu:n #1 { \fbox{\strut #1~(mid)} }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_lastmenu:n #1 { \fbox{\strut #1~(last)} }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_singlemenu:n #1 { \fbox{\strut #1~(single)} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength{\parskip}{1cm}
\begin{document}
\menu{1,2,3,4}

\menu{Single Element}

\menu{A,B,C,D,E}

\setmenuseparator{/}
\menu{C:/Nutzer und Einstellungen/Desktop/Test}

\menu*{C:\Nutzer und Einstellungen\Desktop\Test} 
\end{document}
```

You have only to give sensible definitions to the six functions `\tobi_Xmenu`.

EDIT: I've added support also for `\` as separator; it should be called as `\menu*` (and doesn't need a previous `\setmenuseparator`).

---

### Important change

Due to the changes made to `expl3`, here's a new (cleaned up) version of the code above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_tobi_menu_seq
\tl_new:N \l_tobi_sep_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_tobi_sep_tl { , } % default
\tl_const:Nx \c_tobi_backslash_tl { \cs_to_str:N \\ }

\NewDocumentCommand{\setmenuseparator}{ m }
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tobi_sep_tl { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\menu}{ s m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \tobi_menu_process_rescan:n { #2 }
   }
   {
    \tobi_menu_process:n { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \tobi_menu_process:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:NVn \l_tobi_menu_seq \l_tobi_sep_tl { #1 }
   \tobi_premenu:
   \int_case:nnF { \seq_count:N \l_tobi_menu_seq }
     {
      { 0 } { EMPTY }
      { 1 } { \tobi_singlemenu:n { \seq_map_function:NN \l_tobi_menu_seq \use:n } }
     }
     {
      \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tobi_menu_seq \l_tmpa_tl
      \seq_pop_right:NN \l_tobi_menu_seq \l_tmpb_tl
      \tobi_firstmenu:n { \l_tmpa_tl}
      \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tobi_menu_seq { \tobi_midmenu:n { ##1 } }
      \tobi_lastmenu:n { \l_tmpb_tl }
     }
   \tobi_postmenu:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tobi_menu_process_rescan:n #1
 {
  \group_begin:
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_tobi_sep_tl \c_tobi_backslash_tl
  \tl_set_rescan:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl {\char_set_catcode_other:N \\ } { #1 }
  \tobi_menu_process:V \l_tmpa_tl
  \group_end:
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {NV}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tobi_menu_process:n {V}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \tobi_premenu: { \fbox{\strut pre} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tobi_postmenu: { \fbox{\strut post} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tobi_firstmenu:n #1 { \fbox{\strut #1~(first)} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tobi_midmenu:n #1 { \fbox{\strut #1~(mid)} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tobi_lastmenu:n #1 { \fbox{\strut #1~(last)} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tobi_singlemenu:n #1 { \fbox{\strut #1~(single)} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength{\parskip}{1cm}
\begin{document}
\menu{1,2,3,4}

\menu{Single Element}

\menu{A,B,C,D,E}

\setmenuseparator{/}
\menu{C:/Nutzer und Einstellungen/Desktop/Test}

\menu*{C:\Nutzer und Einstellungen\Desktop\Test} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but is this really easier? I don’t use Windows but others may like it :-/

Comment: @Tobi: If you are a little bit familiar with the new syntax it is easier and of course clearer

Comment: Here's a way (with some limitations)

Comment: @egreg I'd be more comfortable with both arguments being grabbed by `\menu` in the first instance.

Comment: Has there been a further change to `expl3`? The code under 'Important change' fails with this: `Forbidden control sequence found while scanning definit
ion of \tobi_menu_process:n.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.28    \int_case:nnn
                      { \seq_count:N \l_tobi_menu_seq }
`

Comment: @sgmoye Yes, `\int_case:nnn` has become `\int_case:nnF`. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

We can handle this issue only using TeX primitives. The code is more compact and we need not any LaTeX packages:

```
\def\menubox#1{\vbox{\hrule\hbox{ #1 \vrule height12pt depth5pt}\hrule}}
\def\menu{\hbox\bgroup\catcode`\\=12 \menuA}
\def\setmenusep#1{\expandafter\setmenusepA\string#1\end}
\def\setmenusepA#1#2\end{%
   \def\menuA##1{\def\tmp{}\hbox{\vrule\menubox{pre}}\menuB##1#1\end#1}
   \def\menuB##1#1##2#1{%
      \ifx\end##2\ifx\tmp\empty \def\tmp{single}\else \def\tmp{last}\fi\fi
      \ifx\tmp\empty\def\tmp{first}\fi
      \menubox{##1 (\tmp)}%
      \def\tmp{middle}%
      \ifx\end##2\menubox{post}\let\next=\egroup
      \else\menubox{sep}\def\next{\menuB##2#1}\fi
      \next
}}
\setmenusep ,

% TEST:
\menu{1,2,3,4}
\medskip

\menu{Single Element}
\medskip

\setmenusep /
\menu{C:/Nutzer und Einstellungen/Desktop/Test}
\medskip

\setmenusep \\
\menu{C:\Nutzer und Einstellungen\Desktop\Test}

\bye
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `listofitems` approach.  I have also implemented an approach that can also use `\thebackslash` as a separator; however, a `\` cannot be the last character of the string. (I don't think the other solutions work in that case either).  The separator can be string of characters.  If you want to use `!` in the separator, you need to say something like `\setMenuseparator[+]{!}` where the `+` or any other chosen token is not part of the main argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\def\tw@first@element#1{\fbox{\strut#1 (first)}}
\def\tw@middle@element#1{\fbox{\strut#1 (mid)}}
\def\tw@last@element#1{\fbox{\strut#1 (last)}}
\def\tw@single@element#1{\fbox{\strut#1 (single)}}

\def\tw@separator{\fbox{\strut sep}}
\def\tw@precode{\fbox{\strut pre}}
\def\tw@postcode{\fbox{\strut post}}

\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\Menu[1]{%
  \edef\tmp{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \greadlist*\Menulist{\tmp}%
  \tw@precode%
  \ifnum\listlen\Menulist[]=1\relax%
    \tw@single@element{\Menulist[1]}%
  \else%
    \foreachitem\i\in\Menulist{%
      \ifnum\icnt=1\relax
        \tw@first@element{\i}%
      \else%
        \tw@separator%
        \ifnum\icnt=\listlen\Menulist[]\relax
          \tw@last@element{\i}%
        \else%
          \tw@middle@element{\i}%
        \fi%
      \fi%
    }%
  \fi%
  \tw@postcode%
}

\edef\tmp{\detokenize{\ }}
\def\tmpA#1#2\relax{#1}
\edef\thebackslash{\expandafter\tmpA\tmp\relax}

\newcommand\setMenuseparator[2][!]{%
  \ifx\thebackslash#2%
    \expandafter\setsepchar\expandafter{\thebackslash}%
  \else%
    \setsepchar[#1]{#2}%
  \fi%
}
\setMenuseparator{,}

\makeatother


\setlength{\parskip}{1cm}
\begin{document}
\Menu{1,2,3,4}

\Menu{Single Element}

\Menu{A,B,C,D,E}

\setMenuseparator{/}
\Menu{C:/Nutzer und Einstellungen/Desktop/Test}

\setMenuseparator{\thebackslash}
\Menu{C:\Nutzer und Einstellungen\Desktop\Test} 
\end{document}
```

[image]