# Formatting menu-sequences in a program's user manual?

Tags: formatting

In user-manuals, we have lots of text that describe how to access a particular menu in a program, like:

```
Tools -> Web Developer -> Page source

Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Certificates -> View certificates

Start -> Run -> "cmd" ↵
```

Are there any packages which specialise in formatting that type of thing nicely?

Comment: `menukeys` perhaps, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95832/how-to-create-windows-8-styled-menus/ (the package originated from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44961/improve-list-parsing-command)

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40613

Answer (score 0):

Awesome!  From comments:

`Torbjørn T -> LianTze Lim ->` [How to create Windows-8-styled menus?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95832/how-to-create-windows-8-styled-menus/) `-> menukeys`

[image: menu example]